# Integral of product of matrix exponentials

Tags: matrix-calculus

Is there an analytic expression for

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-At}e^{-Bt} dt
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are non-commuting matrices?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general analytic expression. However, the integral (when it exists) satisfies [Sylvester's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), 
$$
AX + XB = \text{Id},
$$
and can be computed using specialized algorithms, such as the [Bartels–Stewart algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm).

Surprisingly, neither of these links mentions the connection to exponential integrals.